# Running Flask app from cli gives "no module named flaskr"

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to run the example flaskr app using the Flask 0.11 cli.  However, I get `ImportError: no module named flaskr`.  I have set `FLASK_APP` and `import flaskr` works in a Python shell.  How do I run the flaskr app with the cli?

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
flask run  # gives ImportError
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have not installed your app in your virtualenv, add `.py` at the end of the module name.

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr.py
```