# flask.cli.NoAppException: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "flaskr". Use "FLASK_APP=flaskr:name to specify one

Tags: python, flask

I am building a python web application using flask and following tutorial from http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/ . I am running the flask from the parent directory but getting following error.

```
(venv) E:\python-code\python-web>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "flaskr" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 294-690-396
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019 13:10:43] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python-code\python-web\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "e:\python-code\python-web\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 95, in find_best_app
    module=module.__name__
flask.cli.NoAppException: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "flaskr". Use "FLASK_APP=flaskr:name to specify one.
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019 13:10:43] "GET /hello?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019 13:10:43] "GET /hello?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019 13:10:43] "GET /hello?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019 13:10:43] "GET /hello?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019 13:10:44] "GET /hello?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019 13:10:44] "GET /hello?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Please help.

I have tried [Running Flask app from cli gives "no module named flaskr"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417060/running-flask-app-from-cli-gives-no-module-named-flaskr)
and 
[flask.cli.NoAppException: Failed to find application in module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52342274/flask-cli-noappexception-failed-to-find-application-in-module)

Comment: Set `set FLASK_APP=flaskr` and `set FLASK_ENV=development` in the Windows cmd and then run `flask run`. This is required to tell Flask where to find your application and to run it in Development mode.

Comment: Yes, I have followed those steps as well.

Answer (score 12):

I have found my problem. I was missing `return app` as the last statement in my code. Sorry for confusion and apologies.

Comment: You forgot it in the `__init__.py` on `create_app` func , right ? For others in the same case, it might be interesting to know where you forgot it.

Comment: I had this error, return app was missing at the end of `create_app` in the app __init__ file

Comment: I defined the method `create` instead of `create_app`

Comment: in my case, there was an empty __init__.py that was created by the IDE and i didn't see it, it stopped flask to run properly :|

Answer (score 2):

I got that error

> flask.cli.NoAppException flask.cli.NoAppException: Failed to find
> Flask application or factory in module "flaskr". Use
> "FLASK_APP=flaskr:name to specify one.

I tried all answers, and it got resolved after I changed the function name from create_function to **create_app**

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions just like the official tutorial said but still got the same error.

My problem was with the IDE that I was using ( Pycharm )

Even though I had an **init**.py file in the flaskr directory, it still wasn't considered as a package.

So I deleted the flaskr directory and created a "new package". Then just copy the code in the **init**.py and that'll solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

is your application dir not named properly? for example, if you wrote `FLASK_APP=flaskr` but your project name is something else, you will get this error. Also, what is in your `flaskr/flaskr/__init__.py` file if the project is named `flaskr` like in the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You **can't name** the FLASK_APP enviroment var as **Flask.py.** Try with another name please and try again.

**No puedes poner el nombre** de la variable de ambiente FLASK_APP **como Flask.py.** Prueba cambiando el nombre del archivo.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the OS you are using you need to export flaskr in your environment

For Linux and Mac:

```
export FLASK_APP=flaskr
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

For Windows cmd, use set instead of export:

```
set FLASK_APP=flaskr
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

For Windows PowerShell, use $env: instead of export:

````
$env:FLASK_APP = "flaskr"
$env:FLASK_ENV = "development"
flask run```
````

Comment: I did exactly as mentioned in the tutorial